# Model pop up does not show when link button is triggered

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a ModalPopupExtender, when I click on link button I want to show the pop up. Now it is not working. Please let me know the changes I should do in my code. My code is, MY popup controle

```
  <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" runat="server" 
   BehaviorID="modalPopupExtender2" 
   TargetControlID="hfHidden"
   PopupControlID="Div2" 
   OkControlID="cancel1" 
   BackgroundCssClass="modalPopup" >
  </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

My link button(it placed inside a grid view as an item template)

```
  <asp:LinkButton ID="View" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Employeeid")%>' OnClick="edit">Edit/View</asp:LinkButton>
```

My link button click event handler,

```
 protected void edit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        LinkButton btndetails = sender as LinkButton;
        GridViewRow gvrow1 = (GridViewRow)btndetails.NamingContainer;
        uname.Text= gvrow1.Cells[1].Text;
        ddrelationship2.SelectedItem.Text = gvrow1.Cells[2].Text;
        udob.Text = gvrow1.Cells[3].Text;
        this.ModalPopupExtender2.Show();
    }
```

Div2 contains some text box and all .
UI is
[image]

Comment: try debugging your code and check what is happening at `Edit`

Comment: Do you have <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager/> in your code?

Comment: @ nadeem, I did, there no errors and debugs correctly..

Comment: Try wrapping your HTML code inside an `UpdatePanel`

Comment: Can you show the markup for where you define Div2?  I've done a quick test on some of my code where I replaced my server side asp:Panel with a Div and was able to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the following in your web.config:

```
<system.web>
 <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" smartNavigation="false">
```